# unhashable type: 'dict' Type Error

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

Suppose I have this dictionary:

```
items = {1: {'title': u'testing123', 'description': u'testing456'},
2: {'description': u'testing123', 'description': u'testing456'},
3: {'description': u'testing123', 'description': u'testing456'},
4: {'description': u'testing123', 'description': u'testing456'},
5: {'description': u'testing123', 'description': u'testing456'},
6: {'description': u'somethingelse', 'description': u'somethingelse'}}
```

I want to filter out the duplicate values, so that in the end I'd get

```
{1: {'title': u'testing123', 'description': u'testing456'}, 6: {'title': u'something', 'description': u'somethingelse'}}
```

I wrote this code:

```
dic = {}

for key, value in items.items():
    if not set(value.values()).issubset(set(dic.values())):
        dic[key] = value
```

however I get the error message `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`. I am not sure why this happens and how to fix it.

This is inspired by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435395/removing-duplicate-items-by-value-within-a-dict) and my failed attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dic.values() return list of dict

```
>>> for key, value in items.items():
...     print dic.values()
...
[{'description': u'testing456', 'title': u'testing123'}]
[{'description': u'testing456', 'title': u'testing123'}]
[{'description': u'testing456', 'title': u'testing123'}]
[{'description': u'testing456', 'title': u'testing123'}]
[{'description': u'testing456', 'title': u'testing123'}]
[{'description': u'testing456', 'title': u'testing123'}]
>>>
```

So, you can't apply set on dict as dict is not hashable.

Btw you can fix it by:

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> for key, value in items.items():
...     if not set(value.values()).issubset(set(sum([x.values() for x in dic.values()],[]))):
...         dic[key] = value
...
>>> dic
{1: {'description': u'testing456', 'title': u'testing123'}, 6: {'description':     u'somethingelse', 'title': u'somethingelse'}}
>>>
```

For python > 3.x

```
if not set(value.values()).issubset(set(sum([list(x.values()) for x in list(dic.values())],[]))):
```

Comment: When I run the code I get `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict_values") to list`. I am on Python 3.4

Comment: for python 3.4 please try like this: if not set(value.values()).issubset(set(sum([list(x.values()) for x in list(dic.values())],[]))):

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If you must use a set, as others have noted you have to use a hashable object like a tuple:

```
unique_items = set()
for k, v in items.items():
    sorted_v = tuple(sorted((k2, v2) for k2, v2 in v.items()))
    unique_items.add(sorted_v)
unique_items = dict(unique_items)
```

gives for `unique_items`:

```
{1: {'description': u'testing456', 'title': u'testing123'},
 6: {'description': u'somethingelse', 'title': u'somethingelse'}}
```

If `items` is not huge (or, at least if the output dictionary isn't expected to be huge):

```
items = {1: {'title': u'testing123', 'description': u'testing456'},
2: {'title': u'testing123', 'description': u'testing456'},
3: {'title': u'testing123', 'description': u'testing456'},
4: {'title': u'testing123', 'description': u'testing456'},
5: {'title': u'testing123', 'description': u'testing456'},
6: {'title': u'somethingelse', 'description': u'somethingelse'}}

unique_items = {}
for k, v in items.items():
    if v not in unique_items.values():
        unique_items[k] = v
```

(assuming the first key in your dictionary example should have been `title`). But you can't predict what the keys to this dictionary will be if duplicates do exist in `items`.

Comment: Solving the original problem is not what I am asking. Please address the main issue of this question which concerns the reason behind the error I receive.

Comment: Ah - OK: didn't realise you were looking for a `set`-based solution. I've edited my answer to provide one.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a set of dicts, but that's not possible, since dicts are unhashable (because they are mutable -- whether they are equal can change as you modify/add/remove pairs in the dict).

Perhaps instead of using the dicts, you can use tuples of their values for your set, a la `if not set((v['description_a'], v['description_b]) for v in value.values()).issubset((v['description_a'], v['description_b]) for v in set(dic.values())):` or similar?

Comment: That's not a set of dicts, that's a set of dict values. Big difference!

Comment: In fact, that part of the code works quite fine. The error is in the part when I do the assignment `dic[key] = value`